# Need GestureColor as transparent

Tags: android

I am implementing Gesture in my Activity in Android.
Every time I am performing a Gesture, a yellow line is being drawn on the screen.

How would I set the GestureColor to transparent?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting .setGestureVisible to false.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at `GestureOverlayView` instead of just `Gesture`. With this class, you can easily put a color to the Gesture using setGestureColor. [Check here for doc.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html)